# MSYS2 + mingw refuses to compile 64-bit vim for Windows

Tags: gcc, vim, mingw, msys2

I was following the guide in https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALLpc.txt
(Section 2 - Msys2 with MinGW)

I've installed msys2 and ran it through the mingw64 file in the msys64 directory, installed all dependencies, etc. I got until 2.4
[2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qrwy.png).

I navigated to the SRC folder of the vim 8.1 installation and ran the command, but I got this error when I run **make -f Make_ming.mak GUI=no**

```html
    $ make -f Make_ming.mak
    g++ -I. -Iproto - ..[omitted].. -luuid
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/buffer.o:buffer.c:(.text+0xf01): undefined reference to `python3_buffer_free'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/eval.o:eval.c:(.text+0xea4): undefined reference to `set_ref_in_python3'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/evalfunc.o:evalfunc.c:(.text+0x4505): undefined reference to `python3_enabled'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/evalfunc.o:evalfunc.c:(.text+0x6990): undefined reference to `do_py3eval'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/evalfunc.o:evalfunc.c:(.text+0x7bd2): undefined reference to `do_py3eval'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_cmds2.o:ex_cmds2.c:(.text+0x277d): undefined reference to `ex_py3file'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_cmds2.o:ex_cmds2.c:(.text+0x2891): undefined reference to `ex_py3'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_cmds2.o:ex_cmds2.c:(.text+0x28a1): undefined reference to `ex_py3do'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_docmd.o:ex_docmd.c:(.rdata+0x4fa8): undefined reference to `ex_py3'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_docmd.o:ex_docmd.c:(.rdata+0x4fc8): undefined reference to `ex_py3do'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_docmd.o:ex_docmd.c:(.rdata+0x4fe8): undefined reference to `ex_py3'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/ex_docmd.o:ex_docmd.c:(.rdata+0x5008): undefined reference to `ex_py3file'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/main.o:main.c:(.text+0x2785): undefined reference to `python3_end'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/window.o:window.c:(.text+0x569a): undefined reference to `python3_window_free'
    C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: gobjx86-64/window.o:window.c:(.text+0x6117): undefined reference to `python3_tabpage_free'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [Make_cyg_ming.mak:1042: gvim.exe] Error 1
```

I am slowly losing my mind, I've spent 3 days trying to get this to compile. I've also tried approaches with windows-native mingw32 (chocolatey), tried cross-compiling from WSL ubuntu, compiling inside of msys2 instead of mingw64 terminal.. The purpose of this is to eventually compile a specific version of vim (8.1) with a specific version of python (3.7).

Here is what is installed on my msys:

```html
$ pacman -Qqe
base
base-devel
filesystem
mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils
mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-ada
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-objc
mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-multiarch
mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-libgccjit
mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-make
mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf
mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-winstorecompat-git
msys2-runtime
```

and the locations/versions of my compilers

```html
C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe

C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe

C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
```

I most often refuse to request help unless I am extremely desperate and out of options, so I apologize if this question was written poorly or difficult to understand.

Comment: Have you tried `mingw32-make -f Make_ming.mak PYTHON3=C:/tools/msys64/mingw64 PYTHON3_HOME=C:/tools/msys64/mingw64 PYTHON3INC=-IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.6m DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes PYTHON3_VER=36 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=libpython3.6m.dll STATIC_STDCPLUS=yes`?

Comment: @Doj
Yes I've tried that as well. The error this time is "if_python3.c:69:10: fatal error: 

Python.h: No such file or directory
   69 | #include <Python.h>"

Mingw came with python 3.9 though, so I replaced the include flag to python3.9, and the dynamic_python3dll to libpython3.9.dll (which exists there) this time I get an error:
    if_python3.c:606:5: error: '_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL' undeclared; did you mean '_Py_DECREF'?

Which after some digging seems to be a problem with this version of python itself.
    bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1808721

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Python 3.9, _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL was removed completely without any substitute. [Thread (redhat.com).](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1808721) It will not build certain versions of vim. I installed Python3.6 through chocolatey, and everything compiled and linked perfectly.

For future reference, first install a version of python3 that works

```
(choco install python --version=3.6.7)
```

then use this in mingw64 shell in src folder of vim:

```
> mingw32-make -f Make_ming.mak PYTHON3=C:/Python36
PYTHON3_HOME=C:/Python36 PYTHON3INC=-IC:/Python36/include DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes 
PYTHON3_VER=36 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=libpython36.dll 
STATIC_STDCPLUS=yes
```

Comment: You might want to [notify](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) the Vim developers of that issue with 3.9.